# SharePoint 2010: Where is the schema.xml for the OOTB blog lists?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, site-definition

*Question:*

---

Where is the **schema** of the OOTB blog lists defined? (i.e. for the Posts, Categories and Comments lists)

The list templates and instances are embedded in the **onet.xml** of the OOTB blog site template at **14/TEMPLATE/Blog**, however there is no mention of the lists' content types, fields or views.

*Background:*

---

I have created a **custom site definition** (based on a copy of the OOTB blog site template) so that we can apply branding and other customisations to our blogs.

Some of these customisations are performed by a feature receiver that is activated as part of the site def. Unfortunately, the order in which SharePoint provisions items from the **onet.xml** is as follows:

> - Site is provisioned
> - Features are activated
> - Feature receivers are activated
> - Other elements (such as lists) defined in the site definition's
>     onet.xml are provisioned

As you can see, the feature receivers (which in my case are trying to update the permissions of the Comments and Categories lists) are activated **before the lists have been created**. The solution to this is very simple: just create the lists as part of the feature as per normal.

To do this, I need to create a list definition in Visual Studio, however I can't find the schema.xml files for these OOTB lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a similar project, but I found those schema under 14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplate\Blog\Lists\Categories or \Posts or \Comments

in your solution you have to have the same mapping as far as I know

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, the schema files are exactly where you say. What do you mean though by "in your solution you have to have the same mapping"?